# Show basic open sets in $\{0,1\}^{A}$ are both open and closed

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Consider the topological space $\{0,1\}^A$. The set of functions from an arbitrary index set $A$ to $\{0,1\}$. Then a subbasis for the product topology is $S=\{U(a,\delta)\mid a \in A,\delta \in\{0,1\}\}$ where $U(a,0)=\pi_a^{-1}(0),U(a,1)=\pi_a^{-1}(1)$. Show that every basic open set is both open and closed.

Attempt: A basic open set is of the form $$\pi_{a_1}^{-1}(b_1) \cap \dots \cap \pi_{a_n}^{-1}(b_n)$$

where $b_i \in \{0,1\},a_i \in A$. Then $$\{0,1\}^A-(\pi_{a_1}^{-1}(b_1) \cap \dots \cap \pi_{a_n}^{-1}(b_n))=\pi_{a_1}^{-1}(c_1) \cap \dots \cap \pi_{a_n}^{-1}(c_n)$$ where $c_i \neq b_i$. Another basic open set. So basic open sets are both open and closed.

Comment: $X^A$ has this property if and only if for each open $U \subset X$ also its complement $X \setminus U$ is open. This applies to each discrete $X$.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is simple: the subbasis open sets $\pi_a^{-1}[\{0\}], \pi_a^{-1}[\{1\}]$ are clopen because $\{0\}, \{1\}$ are clopen in $\{0,1\}$.

So their generated base also consists of clopens sets as *finite* intersections of open sets are open and intersections of closed sets are closed. QED.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that $\{0,1\}$ is endowed with the discrete topology, then every subbasic open set of the product space $\{0,1\}^{A}$ is a preimage under a continuous function of a clopen subset of $\{0,1\}$. Then, every basic open set is a finite intersection of clopen subsets.